# How to create 2 preview button in a post?

Tags: customization, wp-editor, buttons

I have 2 wp-editor in a single post. One is for english language and 2nd for chinese language. Preview button is working for only english language. But i want to preview for chinese language too. How's this possible to preview a post for both wp-editor in a single post?

Comment: Hi Nehal. How did you add the second editor? Through a translation plugin like QTranslate X, or through post meta with ACF / custom metabox?

Comment: Through custom metabox @PedroCoitinho

Comment: sorry was away for a few days! You could look at adding a custom query var that sets the language for the user, keep track of the current language using a cookie and set it with jQuery in the admin. On the front-end hook into `template_redirect` or `pre_get_post` to check for the cookie and add the query var, which is used to load the correct language. However ... Its complicated. I would advise on using a plugin like QTranslate X, Pollylang or WPML.